# GSM modem not attached as ttyUSB on Tomato firmware

Tags: linux, usb

Want to connect gsm modem (Huawei E160G) to router ASUS RT-N18U under Advanced Tomato firmware. But dont know what usb device specify in dongle configuration file `dongle.conf`. Which use Asterisk for connection to modem.

Modem recognized on my laptop with CentOS as three devices in `/dev/ttyUSB0-2`. But when i plug this modem into router `ttyUSB*` devices are not recognized.

After attaching, see in `/var/log/message`

```
May 27 10:23:00 unknown kern.info kernel: usb 2-2: new high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5829]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.0 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5835]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.1 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
May 27 10:23:00 unknown user.debug hotplug[5836]: Attached USB device 2-2:1.2 [INTERFACE=255/255/255 PRODUCT=12d1/1001/0]
```

See the new characted device in `/dev`:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 189, 131 May 27 10:23 usbdev2.4
```

But it is the one and asterisk cant connect to it.

```
[May 27 07:33:06] WARNING[6233]: chan_dongle.c:235 opentty: tcgetattr() failed for /dev/usbdev2.4: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What the is problem?

I think the drivers are missing. On my laptop, where modem work ok i see in `cat /proc/bus/usb/devices` `Driver=option`, but on router output `cat /proc/bus/usb/devices` show that the `Driver=(none)` but it is on the

```
/lib/modules/2.6.36.4brcmarm/kernel/drivers/usb/option.ko
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is enable on WAN mode 3g/modem then /dev/ttyUSB devices became available. But i dont want to use internet from 3g modem. I configured 2 WAN interfaces. First use for real WAN (PPPoE) and second for 3g which will be unusable as inet gateway. 3g can be enbale only by manual (see settings in web).

There is the way for have gsm modem available after rebooting or even after shutdown the router.

Thank for all)